# Does the Torah speak about mental illness?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

I was wondering where does the Torah speak about mental illness, our reaction to mental illness and what is a person who has mental illness obligated to be accounted for?

Comment: When you use the word Torah, do you mean the 5 books of Moses, the Tankah, or the entire corpus of Jewish literature?

Comment: The word for someone who is mentally ill is "shoteh". You'll find a lot googling this term.

Comment: @ShamanSTK, I'm no expert in mental illness or _sh'tus_, but suspect that they overlap but do not coincide.

Comment: @msh210 I'm an expert on the former but not the later. But I was responding to the "obligated to be accounted" part. A shoteh is undoubtedly mentally ill, and learning the criteria on who qualifies as a shoteh would be illuminating on the Torah's perspective on mental illness, imo.

Comment: According to Malbim King Shaul was bipolar. (He phrased it melancholy, but that was the official term back then)

Comment: I have a good chidush on the Klalot of Bechukotay

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. I wonder if there is book out there i can read regarding the issue.

Comment: Question's closed but-It's not Torah, but in I Samuel 21:14-16, Chabad translates it as "And he changed his speech before their eyes, and feigned insanity before them. And he scribbled on the doors of the gate, and let his saliva run down upon his beard."".And Achish said to his bondsmen, "Behold, you see a man who is mad. Why do you bring him to me?""Do I lack lunatics, that you have brought this one to rave in my presence? Will this one come into my house?"  Seems like mental illness was nothing new, even then.